# Use print statements to find out the character for the hexadecimal code "5A"

Tags: java, string, char, hex

```
String b = "5A";
int bConv = Integer.parseInt(b, 16); 
char $2 = bConv;
```

When I try this I get a possible loss of precision error warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because an `int` by default takes 4 bytes, a `char` takes 2 bytes. So by casting you might lose data.

An explicit cast will remove the warning:

```
String b = "5A";
int bConv = Integer.parseInt(b, 16); 
char $2 =(char)bConv;
```

Side note: In my opinion `$2` is a bad name for a variable.

---

**UPDATE**

> Is there a better way to represent characters using hexadecimal values?

Don't know if it can be considered *better*, but you can assign the hex value directly to the character:

```
char myHexChar = 0x5A; //0x tells the compiler that the value is in hex format
```

If you print that variable, you'll get `Z`

Comment: Is there a better way to represent characters using hexadecimal values?